# Angular app vs AEM Angular SPA rest endpoints not responding in time

Tags: angular, aem

I have 2 almost identical applications. One is built in Angular and integrates with a .net backend. The other is the same Angular code base which is then hosted on an AEM platform and integrates with the same .net backend.

The issue I am facing is that on the AEM version is that the rest endpoint don't respond in time. Example, if I log in to the application on the Angular code base I see the first endpoint call console.log response immediately however on the AEM application I first see null values and then eventually I get the response.

Here is a code example

```
  getStoredData() {
    const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(`oidc.user:${environment.accessTokenApiUrl}:${environment.clientId}`));
    console.log(data);
    //In the angular only app I see this data immediately, but on the AEM app I see NULL values and then the data  
    return data;
  }
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Does both applications live in the same infrastructure? That is, there could be network / latency issues between AEM and the .NET back-end.

Comment: @ronnyfm It turned out that AEM does not respond very well to the way Angular makes API requests especially with calls inside of ngOninit so the workaround was to add a delay to each call. This is obviously not ideal but it was the only way we got it to work. It also led me to believe that the SPA capabilities that AEM has is very limited and it should not be used unless there is a specific need. Angular works well on it's own and is excellent at what it does.

To answer your question, yes both environments live on the same infrastructure.